# De-serialize XML String

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

Hello all I have the following XML string generated from file. I want to deserialize it.

```
<CustomerName>TEST</CustomerName>
<PONumber></PONumber>
<ProcessedBy>Jerry Cooke</ProcessedBy>
<ProcessDate>03-05-2004 14:00:49</ProcessDate>
<TagNumber></TagNumber>
<SerialNumber>134</SerialNumber>
```

I am using the following code.

```
string Data =  upperxmlstring
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Data);
                obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                reader.Close();
```

I am getting following exception "**Illegal characters in path.**" This error comes at `XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Data);`
Please help me in solving it.

Comment: Your XML is not a correct document: XML document cannot have multiple root elements.

Answer (score 0):

`new XmlTextReader(string)` expects a filename, not the content. To read the content from a string you'll have to instantiate a `TextReader` for that string. Use `StringReader` for that.

Better still, don't use `XmlTextReader`, since it's been deprecated. Use `XmlReader.Create` instead:

```
string Data = upperxmlstring;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(Data));
obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Comment: Did this work for you? Please accept it as answer if it did.